# SQL SELECT first and 4th number

Tags: postgresql, select

I have ISBN number 9999-02-202-2 in table and I need to check if first digit matches fourth, how to do it using SELECT in postgresql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ANSI SQL:

```
select 
    case when substring('9999-02-202-2' from 1 for 1) = 
              substring('9999-02-202-2' from 4 for 1)
         then 1 else 0 end as matching_flag
```